# Can't connect to SERIAL PORT using Putty

Tags: putty

I want to connect with my serial Port using PuTTY program, but it's not possible, when I ckick "open" nothing happens. I only hear a "Beep, Beep".. under a Windows 7 on MAC OS X with VirtualBox
[image]

Comment: Just so I'm clear - you're running a Windows 7 guest instance on Virtualbox on Mac OSX?  What do you want to connect to using this serial port?

Comment: Try switch OFF and then, ON, the server.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first thing I'd do is make sure you can connect to your external device using the Host OS directly.  Since you're on a Mac you can use screen from the command line (since you're using 9600 baud):

```
screen /dev/ttyS0 9600
```

If that doesn't work then you're dead in the water.

Then make sure your host's serial port is exposed to your Virtual client.  From your host Virtualbox settings you'll need to pass through your serial port (like here https://superuser.com/questions/436049/how-to-use-host-serial-port-from-guest-in-virtualbox).

In Putty then you should be able to connect to the COM port you passed through.

Answer (score 79):

Had this problem and found the solution.
Putty wont open a connection from the "Serial" tab in the left column.
Choose "Session" instead and select the checkbox for Serial.

Comment: The PuTTY interface is a bit confusing.  It has a serial node and a session node on the left panel each of which has a configuration on the right panel. The configuration for the session node actually has a Serial option which is the one we should use.

Comment: For one hour i tried everything, and this was the actual problem. Thanks

Comment: This solved it for me, thank you!

Comment: does not work. Since in Session you cannot change settings.

Answer (score 0):

**More details to the above solution (using "Session" instead of "Serial")**

- USB Adapter 1:1.
- Left side: USB plug.
- Right side: 9-pin-sub-d-plug => Pin 3 on plug: TX from PC (-10V, provided by PC), pin 2 on plug: RX to PC (-7V, provided by embedded device), pin 5: ground. Voltages measured when connected an may vare from -3V to -15V but only if no data are beeing sent.

1. Select the "Serial" tree item in PUTTY on the left side of the little window. Then enter the connection data of your choice into the form on the right side. First of all consider the correct name of the COM-Port which you can find in the device manager (hardware manager) of windows and the baud rate.
2. Next select the "Session" tree item and change the type of the session (maybe former "SSH" or "Telnet" to "Serial" (not in the tree this time but "Serial" in the form with the session settings). Com-Port and Baud-Rate (see list point "1") may appear in the sesssion form. **Session settings (specified in the "Serial" tree item) are globally stored in PUTTY and may have been planned to be started from "Serial" - which does not work - or from "Session"**.
3. Enter a name of your choice into the field "Session->Saved Sessions" and press [Save]. Settings of previous list points plus some additional settings, you have specified, are stored now. When you start PUTTY the next time you can select these settings again and [LOAD] them. Session is stored in registry. A possibility to export may exist.
4. Press [Connect] while "Session" tree item is selected (like written in the first answer post). Terminal should open now.

Answer (score 0):

Had issue with Putty not opening the serial port, Error 2.  Had assumed that com port was set to com1, but checking the Ports under Device Manager found that comport was actually Com5. Setting this as the port in Putty would then connect via serial.